# Extract string up to a different word in each row - R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column containing various words. I also have a separate list of strings (not the same length as the df), and I'd like to create a new column in the dataframe which matches the strings to the words in the column, but only keep the part of the string up to that word.

So for example:
I have this table:

| words |  |
| --- | --- |
| apple |  |
| plant |  |
| banana |  |
| animal |  |
| fly |  |
| ecoli |  |

and these strings of words:

```
stringlist <- c("eukaryote;plant;apple", "eukaryote;plant;banana","eukaryote;animal;dog", "eukaryote;plant;orange" "eukaryote;animal;cat"; "eukaryote;insect;fly", "prokaryote;bacterium;ecoli")
```

and I'd like to get this:

| words | new_words |
| --- | --- |
| apple | eukaryote;plant;apple |
| plant | eukaryote;plant |
| banana | eukaryote;plant;banana |
| animal | eukaryote;animal |
| fly | eukaryote;insect;fly |
| ecoli | prokaryote;bacterium;ecoli |

I've tried something along the lines of :

```
df$words <- c("apple", "plant", "banana", "animal", "fly", "ecoli")
df$new_words<- sub(df$words, "", stringlist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the 'words' column, get the matching 'stringlist' value with `grep`, use `sub` to capture the characters including the word and replace it with backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df$new_words <- sapply(df$words, function(x) 
    sub(sprintf("(.*%s).*", x), "\\1", grep(x, stringlist, 
     value = TRUE)[1]))
```

-output

```
> df
   words                  new_words
1  apple      eukaryote;plant;apple
2  plant            eukaryote;plant
3 banana     eukaryote;plant;banana
4 animal           eukaryote;animal
5    fly       eukaryote;insect;fly
6  ecoli prokaryote;bacterium;ecoli
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(words = c("apple", "plant", "banana", "animal", 
"fly", "ecoli")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

stringlist <- c("eukaryote;plant;apple", "eukaryote;plant;banana", 
"eukaryote;animal;dog", 
"eukaryote;plant;orange", "eukaryote;animal;cat", "eukaryote;insect;fly", 
"prokaryote;bacterium;ecoli")
```

Comment: This works great!! thank you!